# How to use Python to make a web crawler to full-text RSS

Tags: python, rss, web-crawler

I want to write a web crawler in Python that prints only the contents of, for example, a news article.

I tried to do it using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), to print the content inside a `<div>` with a specific id, but every website has a different id for the 'entry' div.

I found [this website](http://ftr.fivefilters.org/makefulltextfeed.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fnews.sky.com%2Fstory%2F1360491%2Fus-ebola-nurse-slams-quarantine-process&max=3) and tried to make a crawler for this website, but I have 2 problems:

1. I don't know if its a good idea to make a crawler for this website, because maybe it will not work one day
2. I tried to print only the text from the website (`fivefilters.org`) but it prints the HTML markup as well. Could someone please show me how to print just the text of the page?

Comment: I've edited your question so that it's a little easier to understand. Where does RSS come into this? Do you just want the text from the RSS feed, or are you using the RSS feed to find the web pages of interest?

Comment: I using the RSS to find web pages, and to take the text from each of the pages.